# How to fix deprecated 'buttonstyle'

Tags: swiftui

With Beta 5 of Xcode 11 I get the warning:

> "'buttonStyle' is deprecated: Use concrete 'PrimitiveButtonStyle' types directly instead."

I tried a couple of things, but didn't find out how to fix this.

```
Button(action: { }) {
    Text("Hello")
}.buttonStyle(.plain)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace `.plain` with `PlainButtonStyle()`:

```swift
Button(action: { }) {
    Text("Hello")
}.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
```